# When I try to fetch data from database it shows warnings and does not execute

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, plugins

I using Woody snippet plugin for PHP code in WordPress. I am trying to display data from a database but it just shows me warnings. It runs fine in my local xampp server without using wordpress.

```php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "myshop");
if ($conn) {
    echo "connection success<br>";
} else {
    echo "error!!!!!";
}
function getPosts()
{
    global $conn;
    $get_products = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $run_products = mysqli_query($conn, $get_products);
    $counter = 1;
    while ($row_products = mysqli_fetch_array($run_products)) {
        $pro_title = $row_products['product_title'];
        echo "<b>$counter" . " $pro_title</b><br>";
        $counter++;
    }
}

getPosts();
```

I already tried `mysqli_num_rows` but it iss not executing in WordPress, it shows "connection success", after that I receive the warnings:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in Z:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\insert-php\includes\shortcodes\shortcode-php.php(45) : eval()'d code on line 15
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in Z:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\insert-php\includes\shortcodes\shortcode-php.php(45) : eval()'d code on line 17

Comment: You should be using the wpQuery class to access your data (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Answer (score 0):

It seem $conn return nothing, Please put below line in your method, or in constructor to reuse in every method

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","myshop");
```